# discord.py tasks.loop() is not executing

Tags: discord.py, task

When i try to start the bot i get the error: **TypeError: generator() missing 1 required positional argument: 'ctx'**

```
async def on_ready():
  activity = discord.Game(name="« g! »", type=3)
  await bot.change_presence(status=discord.Status.online, activity=activity)
  print("Bot is ready!")
  print("---------------------------")
  generator.start()


def pretty(number):
    return ("{:,}".format(number))

def genCode(length):
    code = ''.join(random.SystemRandom().choice(string.ascii_letters + string.digits)
    for _ in range(length))
    return code


@tasks.loop(minutes = 30)
async def generator(ctx, amount: typing.Optional[int] = 100):
    codeStr = ''
    if amount > 100000:
        amount = 100000
    for x in range(amount):
        if x == amount - 1:
            codeStr += "discord.gift/" + genCode(16)
        else:
            codeStr += "discord.gift/" + genCode(16) + "\n"
        if x == amount - 1:
            name = ''.join(random.SystemRandom().choice(string.ascii_letters + string.digits)
            for _ in range(3)) + "codes.txt"
            f = open(name, "x")
            f.write(codeStr)
            f.close()
            await ctx.channel.send(file=discord.File(r'./' + name))
            os.remove(name)
```

Output: https://i.stack.imgur.com/alI4n.jpg

Comment: Is the code that you provided us with this `tasks.loop()` that is not executing? Where are you starting it? What is the expected behavior? You gave us to little details. Please edit your question and add some more of them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error says it all. You can't use ctx in events since ctx represents the Context where command is provoked. Read the docs about ctx here: https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/ext/commands/api.html

In order to send a message to a specific channel use `bot.get_channel(id)` which will return a `discord.Channel` object and then you can use `discord.Channel.send()` to send a message to that channel.

#### Example

```py
channel = bot.get_channel(some_id)
await channel.send("foo")
```

Such bots are against Discord ToS and you risk getting your bot as well as your account getting flagged.